# Save value in database from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

My textfield values are not posted in the postgresql database. I created a simple form named *sample*. This code uses 'sample' in the controller:

```
def sample
  title = params[:title]
  sample=Sample.new(title)
  sample.save()
end`
```

I also created the sample.haml in views:

sample.haml

```
= form_for :sample, url: sample_path do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :title
    %br/
    = f.text_field :title

  %p
    = f.submit
```

And I created the migration file named *20161129160810_create_sample*:

```
class CreateSample < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :samples do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.timestamps
        end
        end
```

When we give the 'title' value and click the submit button, the 'id' value is stored in 'sample' table but the 'title' value shows an empty in the table. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
sample=Sample.new(title: params[:sample][:title])
```

Comment: It's not work,   There is an any  error on form tag in ??

Comment: ah i see you use `f.text_field`.

Answer (score 1):

use `form_tag` (form_tag just generates HTML form tags) instead of `form_for` (form_for generates HTML form associated with a resource in your rails app)

view file `app/views/pages/sample.haml`

```
= form_tag sample_path, :method => 'get' do
  = text_field_tag :title, params[:title]
  = submit_tag "Save"
```

controller route

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/sample' => "pages#sample", :as => :sample
```

then in your controller action `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`

```
def sample
  title = params[:title]
  sample = Sample.create(title: title)
end
```